# How to create a new SNAPSHOT branch from a release tag using mvn release:update-versions?

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

If I create a new branch from a git tag, then the POMs (rightly) contain only non-snapshot versions. So, when I try to use:

```
mvn release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

I get an error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:update-versions (default-cli) on project: 
>        You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.

I can instead checkout the commit *before* the tag, which contains the correct code. But this is not ideal because it is not clear from the git history that it is based on that specific release version.

How can I auto-version a mutli-POM project, starting with a release version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a goal of the `maven-release-plugin` that is specific to creating branch: it is [`branch`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html). Quoting the process made by this goal:

> - Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
> - Change the version in the POMs if you want to change it in the branch (you will be prompted for the versions to use)
> - Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
> - Commit the modified POMs
> - Tag the code in the SCM as a new branch with a version name (this will be prompted for)
> - Bump the version in the POMs if you want to change it to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
> - Commit the modified POMs

This goal will prompt you for the wanted version in the branch and you will be able to specify a SNAPSHOT version. It will also handle multi-module projects just fine if you add the `autoVersionSubmodules` property.

Typical invocation is:

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Same exact issue happened to my build. It was run on Jenkins.
My issue got resolved within Jenkins.
On Jenkins build- GO to Workspace-> wiped out the current Workspace . 
-> Also for PROD build, Most of the time you should be putting the SCM user/pwd for Maven release builds
->Then put a fresh new build number(optional)

And all worked fine.